# Does apache beam in google cloud dataflow keep track of intermediate files in temp location?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In dataflow you specify a temp location for data to be parallelized and then aggregated at the end. I am wondering if it keeps track of which temp files it needs to aggregate in a run. If the same bucket is specified for subsequent runs, and other temp files with different names are left over from previous runs, will it just lazily aggregate everything under the temp folder in the bucket or only the specific temp file names associated with the current run?

Answer (score 2):

Only the ones associated to the current run, since Dataflow is [fault-tolerant](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#parallelization-and-distribution), and may retry your code multiple times in the case of worker issues. The Dataflow service may create backup copies of your code, and can have issues with manual side effects (such as if your code relies upon or creates temporary files with non-unique names).

But is recommended to set an individual bucket for every Job as Jobs based in templates could use the same directory, based on the timestamp of when the template was created
e.g:

```
.temp-beam-2020-01-12_14-13-30-12/
```